# combining and create new columns based on set values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has the following:

```
RECORDID FEEDBACK
1234     Phrase1
1234     Phrase2
1234     Phrase3
1234     ""
1234     notaPhrase but whole lots of words
```

There are a total of 6 phrases that I would like to match then combine into one column. in this example, I need the result to be

```
    RECORDID NewColumn                 FEEDBACK
    1234     Phrase1, Phrase2, Phrase3 notaPhrase but whole lots of words
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Do you need `aggregate(FEEDBACK~RECORDID, df, paste0, collapse = " ")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group by 'RECORDID', select the 'Phrase' elements with a logical index and `summarise` by `paste`ing the 'FEEDBACK' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   filter(!is.na(FEEDBACK) & FEEDBACK != "") %>%
   mutate(flag = str_detect(FEEDBACK, '^Phrase\\d+$')) %>%
   group_by(RECORDID) %>%
   summarise(NewColumn = toString(FEEDBACK[flag]),
             FEEDBACK = toString(FEEDBACK[!flag]))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#   RECORDID NewColumn                 FEEDBACK                          
#      <int> <chr>                     <chr>                             
#1     1234 Phrase1, Phrase2, Phrase3 notaPhrase but whole lots of words
```

NOTE: In the above solution, we are literally matching the words showed in the OP' post.  If it is to count number of words, use `str_count`

```
df1 %>%
   filter(!is.na(FEEDBACK) & FEEDBACK != "") %>%
   mutate(flag = str_count(FEEDBACK, '\\w+') == 1) %>%
   group_by(RECORDID) %>%
   summarise(NewColumn = toString(FEEDBACK[flag]),
             FEEDBACK = toString(FEEDBACK[!flag]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(RECORDID = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L
), FEEDBACK = c("Phrase1", "Phrase2", "Phrase3", "", "notaPhrase but whole lots of words"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: thank you akrun. if my phrases are in a list, does it mean it will be
mutate(flag = str_detect(FEEDBACK, list))